# What's the difference between cylindrical geometry and disk with a hole for topological chiral $p_x\!+\!i p_y$ superconductor?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-insulators, majorana-fermions

We know that for a topological chiral p-wave superconductor  with a cylindrical geometry, i.e. one conserved momentum $k$ and one open boundary direction, there exists  edge modes with opposite momentum in each edge. In particularly, there  exist a zero-energy mode in each edge:

[image]

However, for 2D disk with a hole,  if not apply a magnetic flux in the hole, the boundary condition will be anti-periodic so that there will no zero-energy mode in both of edges: [image]

The argument of the anti-periodic condition is that : the SC order parameter is $\Delta(\mathbf{p})=|\Delta| e^{i \theta} e^{i \phi_\hat{\mathbf{p}}} p$, where $\mathbf{p}=p(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$,and take a quasi-particle around a closed loop will effectively winding $2\pi$ of $\Delta(\mathbf{p})$ since the direction of the momentum of quasi-particle changes $2\pi$, then gives the quasiparticle a negative sign: $$\gamma_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger}=e^{i \theta / 2} u(\mathbf{p}) c_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger}+e^{-i \theta / 2} v(\mathbf{p}) c_{\mathbf{p}}:\gamma^\dagger(x)\mapsto -\gamma^\dagger(-x)$$
My confusion is: I think the picture of disk with a hole and cylinder is totally equivalent so that I cannot understand why they are qualitatively so different.

PS:From the Book of Bernevig, it explains that is is because $\phi_p$ does not wind $2\pi$ for cylinder, but I still don't understand it because if I take the quasi-particle around in the edge, the momentum of it also changes $2\pi$.

Comment: Let me comment from the 2+1D  (3d) Topological quantum field theory  (TQFT) viewpoint (Excuse me.):
$$
\text{2+1D $p_x + ip_y$ superconductor's low energy 3d TQFT = spin-Ising 3d TQFT = $U(2)_{−2,4} \times (SO(3)_1 × U(1)_{−1})$ 3d Chern-Simons field theory}
$$
You will see that place this 3d TQFT on the cylindrical geometry and disk with a hole by solving the appropriate boundary conditions via TQFT useful. You may find help from this https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09298 and References therein.